# Is it possible to increase or decrease the height of each bar in a bar graph based on user on touch event in android using MP android chart library?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to implement an interactive bar graph in android, where the user will be able to touch on each bar and will be able to change its height by its touch. Is it possible to do with the help of [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library in android.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can do that, please go through there documentation https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki

Comment: Thanks! I will go through it.

Comment: [**Here**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample) you can find example code.

Comment: Hi! Thanks Philipp.. I have gone through the example code. I am not looking for a zoom option. Only the length of the bar to be changed not the width or size of the bar and the scale should change accordingly.

Comment: Srinivas were you able to reduce length of a single bar in the bar chart? I have barchart with values inn 100s and one bar with value of 4000 and this distorts the chart. I want to reduce the length of just one bar. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Update- After tying various options I found that it is not possible to reduce length of a single bar of MPAndroid chart programmatically. As a alternative you can hide the value of the particular bar in the chart and display it as text below the chart.